# What would be the most efficient, pure-CSS method for changing the glyph in this menu once toggled?

Tags: css

Fairly straightforward question: I have a responsive, pure-CSS dropdown (checkbox hack) menu using a typical stack menu glyph (burger?) from FontAwesome.

What I would like, because the media menu obviously doesn't close on its own, is to change that glyph to an 'X' indicating it needs to be clicked again in order to close the dropdown.  All of the methods I've come up for this are wildly inefficient (involving a lot of opacity and child-divs), not to mention ugly, and I'm wondering if someone more experienced than I could point out the most (or at least a more) efficient means of doing this.

I've included my working code (which is still messy, I know; this is still in early development).  If anyone could recommend of means of doing this (without resorting to jQuery/JS), I would be so very grateful.

Thank you in advance.

```css
.toggle,
[id^=drop] {
  display: none;
}

nav {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  z-index: 999999;
  visibility: visible;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  font-family: 'Neutra Text TF', Arial, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #00000021;
  height: 80px;
}

nav:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

nav i {
  color: #9b548c;
  font-size: 50px!important;
}

#logo {
  display: block;
  padding: 25px 30px;
  float: left;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 45px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 800;
  position: absolute;
}

#logo h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

#logo a {
  padding: 0;
  font-weight: 800;
  display: inline-block;
}

#logo h1 a {
  font-family: 'Neutra Text TF', Arial, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
  font-size: 25px;
  margin-top: -5px;
}

#logo h2 {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 0px;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-family: 'Neutra Text TF', Arial, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  margin-top: -4px;
}

#logo img {
  display: none;
}

nav ul {
  float: right;
  padding: 25px 30px 0 0;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
}

nav ul li {
  margin: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

nav a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  color: #9b548c;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 100;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.35s;
  transition: all 0.35s;
}

nav ul li ul li:hover {
  color: #000000;
}

nav ul ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 35px;
}

nav ul li:hover>ul {
  display: inherit;
}

nav ul ul li {
  width: 170px;
  float: none;
  display: list-item;
  position: relative;
}

li>a:after {
  content: ' +';
}

li>a:only-child:after {
  content: '';
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
/* MEDIA | TOP NAV */

#logo {
  padding: 4px 0;
  top: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 9;
}

nav {
  margin: 0;
}

nav ul {
  float: right;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
}

.toggle+a,
.menu {
  display: none;
}

.toggle {
  font-family: 'Neutra Text TF', Arial, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
  display: block;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  padding: 5px 0px;
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: none;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 100;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.toggle:hover {
  background-color: red;
}

[id^=drop]:checked+ul {
  display: block;
  color: red;
}

nav ul li {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

nav a {
  font-size: calc(.7em + .7vmin);
}

nav ul ul .toggle,
nav ul ul a {
  padding: 0 40px;
}

nav ul ul ul a {
  padding: 0 80px;
}

nav a:hover,
nav ul ul ul a {
  color: #000000;
}

nav ul li ul li .toggle,
nav ul ul a,
nav ul ul ul a {
  padding: 14px 20px;
  color: #9b548c;
  font-size: 12px;
}

nav ul li ul li .toggle,
nav ul ul a {
  background-color: #ffffffcc;
  font-size: calc(.7em + .7vmin);
}

nav ul ul {
  float: none;
  position: static;
  color: #9b548c;
}

nav ul ul li:hover>ul,
nav ul li:hover>ul {
  display: none;
}

nav ul ul li {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

nav ul ul ul li {
  position: static;
}
}
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/fontawesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!--- BEGIN TOPNAV MENU --->




<nav>
  <div id="logo">
    <h2>

      NAVSUBTITLE

    </h2>
    <h1><a href="/#">

NAVTITLE

   </a></h1>
  </div><label for="drop" class="toggle"><i class="fa fa-align-justify"></i></label>
  <form><input type="checkbox" id="drop" />
    <ul class="menu">

      <li><a href="/#">Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="/#">Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="/#">Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="/#">Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="/#">Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="/#">Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="/#">Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="/#">Link</a></li>




      <!-- START DROP DOWN -->

      <li><label for="drop-1" class="toggle">

SUB MENU +

   </label><a href="#">

SUB MENU

   </a><input type="checkbox" id="drop-1" />
        <ul>


          <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>


        </ul>
      </li>

      <!-- END DROP DOWN -->



      <li><a href="/#">&times;</a></li>
    </ul>
  </form>
</nav>


<!--- END TOPNAV MENU --->
```

Comment: Have you tried placing the close icon beside the burger icon in the HTML, setting it to `display: none` by default and then switching both icons display properties on label check? Alternatively make the burger icon with pure CSS and animate it, there are lots of tutorials for how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
.fa-align-justify:active::before {
    content: "x";
}
```

The basic idea is to use the active selector to register the click and change the icon: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_active.asp

Since you want to be able to click on the whole navbar to expand, you might need to adjust the selector to your needs (e.g. nav:active .fa-align-justify::before or whatever you put the dropdown action on)

You can test this here:

https://jsfiddle.net/vbkmtct4/

```css
.toggle,
[id^=drop] {
  display: none;
}

nav {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  z-index: 999999;
  visibility: visible;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  font-family: 'Neutra Text TF', Arial, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #00000021;
  height: 80px;
}

nav:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

nav i {
  color: #9b548c;
  font-size: 50px!important;
}

#logo {
  display: block;
  padding: 25px 30px;
  float: left;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 45px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 800;
  position: absolute;
}

#logo h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

#logo a {
  padding: 0;
  font-weight: 800;
  display: inline-block;
}

#logo h1 a {
  font-family: 'Neutra Text TF', Arial, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
  font-size: 25px;
  margin-top: -5px;
}

#logo h2 {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 0px;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-family: 'Neutra Text TF', Arial, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  margin-top: -4px;
}

#logo img {
  display: none;
}

nav ul {
  float: right;
  padding: 25px 30px 0 0;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
}

nav ul li {
  margin: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

nav a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  color: #9b548c;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 100;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.35s;
  transition: all 0.35s;
}

nav ul li ul li:hover {
  color: #000000;
}

nav ul ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 35px;
}

nav ul li:hover>ul {
  display: inherit;
}

nav ul ul li {
  width: 170px;
  float: none;
  display: list-item;
  position: relative;
}

li>a:after {
  content: ' +';
}

li>a:only-child:after {
  content: '';
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
/* MEDIA | TOP NAV */

#logo {
  padding: 4px 0;
  top: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 9;
}

nav {
  margin: 0;
}

nav ul {
  float: right;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
}

.toggle+a,
.menu {
  display: none;
}

.toggle {
  font-family: 'Neutra Text TF', Arial, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
  display: block;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  padding: 5px 0px;
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: none;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 100;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.toggle:hover {
  background-color: red;
}

[id^=drop]:checked+ul {
  display: block;
  color: red;
}

nav ul li {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

nav a {
  font-size: calc(.7em + .7vmin);
}

nav ul ul .toggle,
nav ul ul a {
  padding: 0 40px;
}

nav ul ul ul a {
  padding: 0 80px;
}

nav a:hover,
nav ul ul ul a {
  color: #000000;
}

nav ul li ul li .toggle,
nav ul ul a,
nav ul ul ul a {
  padding: 14px 20px;
  color: #9b548c;
  font-size: 12px;
}

nav ul li ul li .toggle,
nav ul ul a {
  background-color: #ffffffcc;
  font-size: calc(.7em + .7vmin);
}

nav ul ul {
  float: none;
  position: static;
  color: #9b548c;
}

nav ul ul li:hover>ul,
nav ul li:hover>ul {
  display: none;
}

nav ul ul li {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

nav ul ul ul li {
  position: static;
}
}

.fa-align-justify:active::before {
    content: "x";
}
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/fontawesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!--- BEGIN TOPNAV MENU --->




<nav>
  <div id="logo">
    <h2>

      NAVSUBTITLE

    </h2>
    <h1><a href="/#">

NAVTITLE

   </a></h1>
  </div><label for="drop" class="toggle"><i class="fa fa-align-justify"></i></label>
  <form><input type="checkbox" id="drop" />
    <ul class="menu">

      <li><a href="/#">Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="/#">Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="/#">Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="/#">Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="/#">Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="/#">Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="/#">Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="/#">Link</a></li>




      <!-- START DROP DOWN -->

      <li><label for="drop-1" class="toggle">

SUB MENU +

   </label><a href="#">

SUB MENU

   </a><input type="checkbox" id="drop-1" />
        <ul>


          <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>


        </ul>
      </li>

      <!-- END DROP DOWN -->



      <li><a href="/#">&times;</a></li>
    </ul>
  </form>
</nav>


<!--- END TOPNAV MENU --->
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to modify your markup for this solution, namely move the `label` into the `form`, and then slightly change your selectors to reflect that change. Also, this solution makes use of the pseudo-element-style instead of the class-based-style of using Font Awesome.

The relevant snippets, for exposition, are:

```
<form>
    <input type="checkbox" id="drop" />
    <label for="drop" class="toggle">
        <i class="icon"></i>
    </label>
    <ul class="menu">
    ...
```

Along with:

```
.toggle .icon::before {
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
  display: inline-block;
  font-style: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  text-rendering: auto;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  font-weight: 900;
  content: '\f039';
}

[id^=drop]:checked ~ ul { /** following-sibling selector instead of immediate-sibling **/
  display: block;
  color: red;
}

[id^=drop]:checked + label .icon::before {
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
  content: "\f00d";
}
```

Full, runnable snippet:

```css
.toggle,
[id^=drop] {
  display: none;
}

nav {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  z-index: 999999;
  visibility: visible;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  font-family: 'Neutra Text TF', Arial, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #00000021;
  height: 80px;
}

nav:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

nav i {
  color: #9b548c;
  font-size: 50px !important;
}

#logo {
  display: block;
  padding: 25px 30px;
  float: left;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 45px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 800;
  position: absolute;
}

#logo h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

#logo a {
  padding: 0;
  font-weight: 800;
  display: inline-block;
}

#logo h1 a {
  font-family: 'Neutra Text TF', Arial, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
  font-size: 25px;
  margin-top: -5px;
}

#logo h2 {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 0px;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-family: 'Neutra Text TF', Arial, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  margin-top: -4px;
}

#logo img {
  display: none;
}

nav ul {
  float: right;
  padding: 25px 30px 0 0;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
}

nav ul li {
  margin: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

nav a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  color: #9b548c;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 100;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.35s;
  transition: all 0.35s;
}

nav ul li ul li:hover {
  color: #000000;
}

nav ul ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 35px;
}

nav ul li:hover>ul {
  display: inherit;
}

nav ul ul li {
  width: 170px;
  float: none;
  display: list-item;
  position: relative;
}

li>a:after {
  content: ' +';
}

li>a:only-child:after {
  content: '';
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  /* MEDIA | TOP NAV */
  #logo {
    padding: 4px 0;
    top: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 9;
  }
  nav {
    margin: 0;
  }
  nav ul {
    float: right;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .toggle+a,
  .menu {
    display: none;
  }
  .toggle {
    font-family: 'Neutra Text TF', Arial, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
    display: block;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    padding: 5px 0px;
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 25px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: none;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 100;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .toggle:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .toggle .icon::before {
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free" !important;
    display: inline-block;
    font-style: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    text-rendering: auto;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    font-weight: 900;
    content: '\f039';
  }
  [id^=drop]:checked~ul {
    display: block;
    color: red;
  }
  [id^=drop]:checked+label .icon::before {
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
    content: "\f00d";
  }
  nav ul li {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
  }
  nav a {
    font-size: calc(.7em + .7vmin);
  }
  nav ul ul .toggle,
  nav ul ul a {
    padding: 0 40px;
  }
  nav ul ul ul a {
    padding: 0 80px;
  }
  nav a:hover,
  nav ul ul ul a {
    color: #000000;
  }
  nav ul li ul li .toggle,
  nav ul ul a,
  nav ul ul ul a {
    padding: 14px 20px;
    color: #9b548c;
    font-size: 12px;
  }
  nav ul li ul li .toggle,
  nav ul ul a {
    background-color: #ffffffcc;
    font-size: calc(.7em + .7vmin);
  }
  nav ul ul {
    float: none;
    position: static;
    color: #9b548c;
  }
  nav ul ul li:hover>ul,
  nav ul li:hover>ul {
    display: none;
  }
  nav ul ul li {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
  }
  nav ul ul ul li {
    position: static;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!--- BEGIN TOPNAV MENU --->
<nav>
  <div id="logo">
    <h2>NAVSUBTITLE</h2>
    <h1><a href="/#">NAVTITLE</a></h1>
  </div>
  <form>
    <input type="checkbox" id="drop" />
    <label for="drop" class="toggle">
     <i class="icon"></i>
  </label>
    <ul class="menu">
      <li><a href="/#">Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="/#">Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="/#">Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="/#">Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="/#">Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="/#">Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="/#">Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="/#">Link</a></li>
      <li>
        <label for="drop-1" class="toggle">SUB MENU +</label>
        <a href="#">SUB MENU</a>
        <input type="checkbox" id="drop-1" />
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="/#">&times;</a></li>
    </ul>
  </form>
</nav>
```

Comment: @Annie Clarke, if you are able to adjust the html, use this solution as it is much more reliable. It is a bit weird to have the label apart from the checkbox in the markup anyways.